# Contiki-OS for Sky/Telos to tranfer an image (25 KB)

Tags: contiki

I am using Sky/Telos and Contiki-OS in one of my project to transfer images. I am trying to broadcast an image from a node (connected with PC) so that other nodes (Connected with PC) are able to capture the image and rebuild it.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try CoAP block transfers. Give `examples/er-rest-example` a try; specifically look into the "chunks" resource.